# Comparing Date Picker date with the current date and applying before() function

Tags: android

I want to compare the date that comes from a datepicker in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" against the current date of the system, and apply the operation `currentdate.before(pickeddate)`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current **Date** with:

```
String pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy";
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
 try {

  Date date = format.parse("01-07-2013");
  System.out.println(date);

 } catch (ParseException e) {

 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**http://kiddyandroid.blogspot.in/2016/03/date-time-in-android.html**

**Getting Current Date:**

```
private SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
public String getCurrentDate() {
    int yr, month, day, hour;
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    yr = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour = today.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    return (yr + "-" + getLength(month + 1) + "-" + getLength(day));
}

public static String getLength(int i) {
    if (i > 9) 
        return "" + i;
    return "0" + i;
}
```

**Comparing current date with Date Picker date:**

```
String fromDate = yr + "-" + month + "-" + day;
public boolean fromDateCheck(String fromDate) {
    try {
        String toDate = 12-02-2013
        Date toDATE = dfDate.parse(toDate);     // dfDate --> Format of Date
        Date fromDATE = dfDate.parse(fromDate);

        if (fromDATE.before(toDATE) || fromDATE.compareTo(toDATE) == 0) {
            // Do the things if FromDate(Current Date) and To Date are same or FromDate is not a Future date
            return true;
        } else if (fromDATE.after(toDATE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Invalid Date",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Choose Correct Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```